# D3DXCreateCylinder is Unreferenced?

Tags: c++, directx-9

i am a novice directx 9 or any version of directx for that matter.
I made a simple program to draw a teapot , i have linked all the libraries 
but this error dosent seem to go:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateCylinder@32 referenced in function _wWinMain@16

CODE:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)
       {
            UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
               UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

// TODO: Place code here.
MSG msg;
HACCEL hAccelTable;

// Initialize global strings
LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadString(hInstance, IDC_DIRECTX9TEST, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

// Perform application initialization:
if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
{
    return FALSE;
}

hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_DIRECTX9TEST));

// Main message loop:
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    direct9 = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS param;

    ZeroMemory(&param, sizeof(param));
    param.Windowed= true;
    param.SwapEffect=D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        param.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;

    direct9->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,hWnd, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,&param, &pDevice);

    pDevice->Clear(1, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 40, 100), 1.0f, 0);

    pDevice->BeginScene();
        // DRAW

LPD3DXMESH cylinder; // Define a pointer to the mesh.

        D3DXCreateCylinder(pDevice, 2.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 10, 10, &cylinder, NULL);
         cylinder->DrawSubset(0);
            cylinder->Release();

    pDevice->EndScene();
    pDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

return (int) msg.wParam;
```

}

THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP!!

EDIT:
typed the full error message
PS:
I AM USING VISUAL STUDIO 2008 WITH DIRECTX SDK JUNE 2010

Comment: Did you include d3d9x.lib in your linker command line?

Comment: I have ! But this error doesn't go!